# Dask read_sql_table errors out when using an SQLAlchemy expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, dask

I'm trying to use an SQLAlchemy expression with dask's read_sql_table in order to bring down a dataset that is created by joining and filtering a few different tables.  The [documentation](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_sql_table) indicates that this should be possible.

(The example below, does not include any joins as they are not needed to replicate the problem.)

I build my connection string, create an SQLAlchemy engine and table corresponding to a table in my database. (I'm using PostgreSQL.)

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Column, MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy.sql import  select


username = 'username'
password = 'password'
server = 'prod'
database = 'my_db'

connection_string = f'postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@{server}/{database}'

engine = create_engine(connection_string)

metadata = MetaData()

t = Table('my_table', metadata,
    Column('id'),
    schema='my_schema')
```

I'm able to build a select and use it with SQLAlchemy with no issue

```
>>> s = select([t]).limit(5)
>>> rp = engine.execute(s)
>>> rp.fetchall()

[(3140757,), (3118225,), (3156070,), (3193075,), (3114614,)]
```

I'm also able to feed the SQLAlchey select to panda's read_sql, which works fine

```
>>> pd.read_sql(s, connection_string)

id
0   3140757
1   3118225
2   3156070
3   3193075
4   3114614
```

However, when I pass the same select to dask, I get a ProgrammingError.  It shows that dask is turning around and calling pandas.read_sql, so you would think it should work, but something is obviously not.

```
>>> dd.read_sql_table(s, connection_string, index_col='id')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\miniconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1192                         parameters,
-> 1193                         context)
   1194         except BaseException as e:

C:\miniconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py in do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    508     def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 509         cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    510 

ProgrammingError: subquery in FROM must have an alias
LINE 2: FROM (SELECT my_schema.my_table.id AS id 
             ^
HINT:  For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-0db95e60f442> in <module>
----> 1 dd.read_sql_table(s, connection_string, index_col='id')

C:\miniconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\io\sql.py in read_sql_table(table, uri, index_col, divisions, npartitions, limits, columns, bytes_per_chunk, head_rows, schema, meta, engine_kwargs, **kwargs)
    116         # derrive metadata from first few rows
    117         q = sql.select(columns).limit(head_rows).select_from(table)
--> 118         head = pd.read_sql(q, engine, **kwargs)
    119 
    120         if head.empty:

C:\miniconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in read_sql(sql, con, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, columns, chunksize)
    395             sql, index_col=index_col, params=params,
    396             coerce_float=coerce_float, parse_dates=parse_dates,
--> 397             chunksize=chunksize)
    398 
    399 

C:\miniconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in read_query(self, sql, index_col, coerce_float, parse_dates, params, chunksize)
   1061         args = _convert_params(sql, params)
   1062 
-> 1063         result = self.execute(*args)
   1064         columns = result.keys()
   1065 

C:\miniconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
    952     def execute(self, *args, **kwargs):
    953         """Simple passthrough to SQLAlchemy connectable"""
--> 954         return self.connectable.execute(*args, **kwargs)
    955 
    956     def read_table(self, table_name, index_col=None, coerce_float=True,

C:\miniconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in execute(self, statement, *multiparams, **params)
   2073 
   2074         connection = self.contextual_connect(close_with_result=True)
-> 2075         return connection.execute(statement, *multiparams, **params)
   2076 
   2077     def scalar(self, statement, *multiparams, **params):

C:\miniconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in execute(self, object, *multiparams, **params)
    946             raise exc.ObjectNotExecutableError(object)
    947         else:
--> 948             return meth(self, multiparams, params)
    949 
    950     def _execute_function(self, func, multiparams, params):

C:\miniconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py in _execute_on_connection(self, connection, multiparams, params)
    267     def _execute_on_connection(self, connection, multiparams, params):
    268         if self.supports_execution:
--> 269             return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
    270         else:
    271             raise exc.ObjectNotExecutableError(self)

C:\miniconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _execute_clauseelement(self, elem, multiparams, params)
   1058             compiled_sql,
   1059             distilled_params,
-> 1060             compiled_sql, distilled_params
   1061         )
   1062         if self._has_events or self.engine._has_events:

C:\miniconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1198                 parameters,
   1199                 cursor,
-> 1200                 context)
   1201 
   1202         if self._has_events or self.engine._has_events:

C:\miniconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _handle_dbapi_exception(self, e, statement, parameters, cursor, context)
   1411                 util.raise_from_cause(
   1412                     sqlalchemy_exception,
-> 1413                     exc_info
   1414                 )
   1415             else:

C:\miniconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py in raise_from_cause(exception, exc_info)
    263     exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb = exc_info
    264     cause = exc_value if exc_value is not exception else None
--> 265     reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
    266 
    267 if py3k:

C:\miniconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py in reraise(tp, value, tb, cause)
    246             value.__cause__ = cause
    247         if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
--> 248             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    249         raise value
    250 

C:\miniconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1191                         statement,
   1192                         parameters,
-> 1193                         context)
   1194         except BaseException as e:
   1195             self._handle_dbapi_exception(

C:\miniconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py in do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    507 
    508     def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 509         cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    510 
    511     def do_execute_no_params(self, cursor, statement, context=None):

ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) subquery in FROM must have an alias
LINE 2: FROM (SELECT my_schema.my_table.id AS id 
             ^
HINT:  For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.
 [SQL: 'SELECT id \nFROM (SELECT my_schema.my_table.id AS id \nFROM my_schema.my_table \n LIMIT %(param_1)s) \n LIMIT %(param_2)s'] [parameters: {'param_1': 5, 'param_2': 5}] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Chris said in a different answer, Dask wraps your query in something of a form `SELECT columns FROM (yourquery)`, which is an invalid syntax for PostgreSQL, because it expects an alias for that parenthesised expression. Without reimplementing the whole `read_sql_table` method, the expression can be aliased simply by adding `.alias('somename')` to your select, i.e.

```
select([t]).limit(5).alias('foo')
```

That expression, when wrapped by Dask, generates correct syntax for Postgres

```
SELECT columns FROM (yourquery) AS foo
```

Answer (score 3):

For any others that run across this question.  read_sql_table does not seem to support this use case (at this time).  If you pass in an SQLAlchemy Select object, it ends up getting wrapped in another SQLAlchemy Select and without an alias, which is bad SQL (at least for PostgreSQL).

Looking at read_sql_table from the dask source, table is the Select object that is passed to read_sql_table and as seen, it gets wrapped in another select.

```
q = sql.select(columns).where(sql.and_(index >= lower, cond)
                              ).select_from(table)
```

The good news is the read_sql_table function is relatively straight forward and the magic is really only a couple lines that create a dataframe from a delayed objects.  You just need to write your own logic to beak the query into chunks

```
parts = []
for query_chunk in queries:
    parts.append(delayed(_read_sql_chunk)(q, uri, meta, **kwargs))

return from_delayed(parts, meta, divisions=divisions)


def _read_sql_chunk(q, uri, meta, **kwargs):
    df = pd.read_sql(q, uri, **kwargs)
    if df.empty:
        return meta
    else:
        return df.astype(meta.dtypes.to_dict(), copy=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

The query sent on that line is auto-generated by SQLAlchemy, so the syntax ought to be correct. However, I notice that your original query includes a `.limit()` modifier. The purpose of the line `head =` is to get the first few rows, to infer types. If the original query already has a limit clause, I can see that the two might conflict. Please try using a query without `.limit()`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and indeed at the bottom of the stack trace I see that limit is being included in the query twice.  Presumably once from my query and once from dask doing the sampling.  I removed limit from my query and I can see in the stack trace that there is now only one limit in the query.  Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me here. The string approach is where I started, e.g., `dd.read_sql_table("""select id from my_schema.my_table""", connection_string, index_col='id').` When I do that I get a NoSuchTableError, which seems to say the string is being interpreted as a table name as opposed to an SQL query.  Based on that error and some other reading I did, I concluded that I needed to use a SQLAlchemy selectable.  But, perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: I would have thought `read_sql_table('my_table', connection_string, index_col='id', schema='my_schema', columns=[..])`. I notice you only have one column and it is to be the index - then you would have no data, which would be a problem.

Comment: So yes good point on only pulling the id and then using it as the index. But the same thing happens with select *.  The example that you have listed does work just fine.  However, I need to make a join, which is why I'm trying to feed it SQL or an SQLAlchemy selectable.

Comment: And the join version still fails when omitting the limit and including more columns than just the index_col? Then this sounds like a genuine bug, but not one I have a quick fix for. The function is relatively short: with breakpoints, you can find what sqlalchemy thinks the query is at each point.

Comment: Yes, it's still failing when omitting limit.  For now, I've put together a quick workaround using pandas' sql_read and chunksize to read the data into dask in chunks.  If I get ambitious, I'll dig into the dask function itself and see what I can figure out.  Thanks so much for all your help.