# How to use Dask to read data from SQL <connection string>?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

There are not enough examples in the documentation on how to read data from sqlAlchemy to a dask dataframe.

Some examples i see are in terms of :

```
   df = dd.read_sql_table(table='my_table_name', uri=my_sqlalchemy_con_url, index_col='id')
```

But my query is not to get the entire table at once and only get (select * from ....table A where .....) kind of query to be passed as parameter.. Also, how to pass connection params are not mentioned.

How to pass connection params from sqlAlchemy connection engine and to pass custom query instead of fetching the whole table.

I understand this is basic but could find no references on this in docs / web

EDIT :

```
     d100 = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/{4}'.format("xx", "xx", "xxxxx.com", "3306", "xxxx") 
     df = dd.read_sql_table(table='select * from ps_g9 limit 10;', uri=d100, index_col='uuid')
```

and i get table doesnt exist error

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentation: https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_sql_table

It lists the following:

- that the "table" parameter can indeed be a table name or any SQL expression, constructed from sqlalchemy instances (i.e., not text)
- that the dictionary `engine_kwargs`, if given, will be passed to sqlalchemy when creating the database query engine

Comment: Put into engine_kwargs all the things you would like to put into engine creation, which includes username/password. Exactly what you might need depend on the specific engine.

Comment: also tried this : d100 = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/{4}'.format("xx", "xx", "xxxxx.com", "3306", "xxxx")

df = dd.read_sql_table(table='select * from ps_g9 limit 10;', uri=d100, index_col='uuid') and i get table doesnt exist

Comment: edited the question to show the exact error , @mdurant

Comment: " constructed from sqlalchemy instances (i.e., not text) " - see https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/tutorial.html

Comment: yea im trying to construct the sqlalecmy version of a complex query and try.,.. did not work so far...but  Thanks fr your help

Comment: The reason for this is, that dask needs to partition your query, and how to do that with a text query would depend on the dialect of SQL being used. Better rely on sqlalchemy to do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196007/discussion-between-viv-and-mdurant).

Answer (score 1):

The default partition size for numeric indexes is 256 MB, unless you specify npartitions.
For string indexes, you can use the `divisions` argument, e.g.

```
... division = sorted(['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow']) ...
```

if you have an index with color names.

See also https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2604.

Futher parameters for sqlalchemy can be passed using the `engine_kwargs` keyword. See also the [read_sql_table docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe-api.html?highlight=sql#dask.dataframe.read_sql_table).

[Here](https://livebook.manning.com/#!/book/data-science-at-scale-with-python-and-dask/chapter-4/v-4/68) is a preview of the relevant chapter of Mannings *Data Science at Scale with Python and Dask* book.

Comment: the question is on how to fetch data from db using sqlalchemy to dask dataframe. and the examples in the offical docs talk about getting entire table using read_sql but example to get subset of data (select * from.... where....) is not given so was asking for examples of this. Updated teh question for clarity as well

Comment: besides table names, you can specify **sqlalchemy expressions**  in the `table` argument, so a `select.where()` should work (untested though). Did you read the github link I gave in my answer, specifically the [6th comment](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2604#issuecomment-389227612)?

Comment: regarding your EDIT: the error is because there is of course no table with the name `'select * from ps_g9 limit 10;'`. See https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/tutorial.html for sqlalchemie expressions.See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54819271/dask-read-sql-table-errors-out-when-using-an-sqlalchemy-expression/54914331).